# Set Negative x-axis values androidplot

Tags: android, graph, androidplot

I don't have any idea in how do in negative values of the x axis in androidplot the graph.

[Here's the picture i want the line in negative x axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qljYY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Androidplot tries to frame whatever series data it's given to maximize screen space usage.  You can change this behavior by manually specifying boundaries, or you can just tell Androidplot to center on a specific point.  In your case:

```
plot.centerOnDomainOrigin(0);
plot.centerOnRangeOrigin(0);
```

Check out the [f(x) demo source](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/demoapp/src/main/java/com/androidplot/demos/FXPlotExampleActivity.java) for a complete example of how it's done.

Comment: what i mean is where i can plot a coordinate is specific x-axis sample (-3,4) thank you

Comment: did you look at the f(x) source?  you can use the SimpleXYSeries and pass both x and y values, instead of just y values as demonstrated in that example.